# Several clients don't connects with RServe

Tags: r, sockets, rserve

I'm trying to connect 2 clients with RServe, but works only the first one. And the second one just waiting for disconnect of first (there is a waiting to receive IDString from server).
How can I solve this problem? I want to make them work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Maybe it will help someone.
That is a limitation of Windows, so unfortunately there is nothing Rserve can do about it (until Microsoft improves Windows). The best option is to use a modern operating system (Linux, OS X , Solaris, BSD, ..), or use multiple Rserve instances with a proxy to switch between them.